# VBScript mysterium - Why isn't network drives connected at logon?

Tags: vbscript, active-directory, network-drive

This is one of the strangest things I've ever seen. I've got this logon script that basically disconnects a set of Network drives and then reconnects them. Previously, all users had a batch file set in their AD profile to run. After I wrote the vbscript, I just run that via the batch script. And it's been working just fine.

Now however, I tried to create a GPO and set the vbscript directly in there. And strangely enough, no network drives are connected. So I began poking around, puttinga msgbox right before the drives are connected. And one right after. Immediatly after login I can see the first textbox appear. After I click OK, the drives are supposed to be connected. But they don't. And right after, I can see the second text box.

What's really weird is that if I run the script manually directly after, everything works just fine! I even tried to put a sleep command on the top of the script now, just in case there's some mismatch in the replication of the domain controllers. But that didn't do anything either.

Here's the script as it is right now:

```
'Run the script
mapNetworkdrives

Public Sub mapNetworkdrives()
    ' Lag WScript.Network-objekt
    Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
    Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'On Error Resume Next

    ' Fjern eksisterende nettverksdrev først
    removeNetworkDrives objFSO, objnetwork

    Dim userName
    userName = objNetwork.UserName

    Dim computerName
    computerName = objNetwork.ComputerName

    ' Sjekk om det er Citrix som blir logget på
    If computerName = "JBC" Then
        If Not isDriveConnected("S", objFso, objNetwork) = True Then
            objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "S:", "\\sharepoint.ourcompany.no\prosj"
        End if
    End if

    ' Sjekk om nettverksdrev er allerede koblet opp

    'objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "Z:", "\\ourcompany.local\files\Brukere\" & username
    objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "P:", "\\ourcompany.local\files\felles"
    objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "Q:", "\\ourcompany.local\files\maler"
    objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "R:", "\\ourcompany\DIY"
    objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "N:", "\\ourcompany\felles\navn"

    Set objNetwork = Nothing
    Set objFSO = Nothing

End Sub

Public Sub removeNetworkDrives(ByVal objFSO, ByVal objNetwork)

    'On Error Resume Next

    If isDriveConnected("Z", objFSO) Then
        objNetwork.RemoveNetworkDrive "Z:", True, True
    End if

    If isDriveConnected("P", objFSO) = True Then
        objNetwork.RemoveNetworkDrive "P:", True, True
    End if

    If isDriveConnected("Q", objFSO) = True Then
        objNetwork.RemoveNetworkDrive "Q:", True, True
    End if

    If isDriveConnected("R", objFSO) = True Then
        objNetwork.RemoveNetworkDrive "R:", True, True
    End if

    If isDriveConnected("N", objFSO) = True Then
        objNetwork.RemoveNetworkDrive "N:", True, True
    End if

    Set objNetwork = Nothing        
End Sub
```

Can anybody see anything that I cannot? Am I missing something here? The very same script works just fine if I run the batch file first, which again runs this very same script. The only thing I can think of is that some DNS server might not be ready or something at the time the script is run.

Comment: Wild shot in the dark here, but have you checked that the script does indeed run as the the currently logged-in user? Eg outputting the `objNetwork.UserName` value in your msgbox?

Comment: This I have NOT done actually! Good point, I did at one point map the Z:\ drive to the user's home folder. Until I found it was already being done in the user's AD profile. I'll go check that out :)

Comment: Just tried this and yes, the correct username is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, this is "normal behaviour" as described here:
http://pcloadletter.co.uk/tag/launchapp-wsf/

Answer (score 0):

It is worth trying checking the privileges of the script.
I've encountered a lot of network shared mapping issues with scheduled/automatic scripts.

Personally, I use batch's "net use" and it solved many weird issues.

Comment: Hmm, good point. But if the privileges of the script is set incorrectly, wouldn't that give problems of running the script manually as well? Cause there's no problems directly after login. Edit: I just tried to specify 'Users' to have Read permissions. But that didn't do any difference.

Comment: are you using scheduled tasks to run this script?

Comment: I suggest that u'll check the logs of your task for error codes etc.

Comment: Not using scheduled tasks. It's only a script set in a GPO as logonscript. Which log should I check, the client side? I don't even have any On error resume next either. I guess I could check to see if any other stuff are in there.